How to Distribute Dask-CUDA Workload Across Multiple GPUs?
I'm working on a project where I need to evenly distribute data processing tasks across multiple GPUs using dask_cudf. Despite my current setup, the workload seems to be handled by only one GPU. I'm looking for advice on how to properly configure Dask-CUDA to utilize all available GPUs effectively.
Current Setup:
I have two NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 GPUs. Here is a simplified version of my current script:
python

import os
import json
import cudf
import dask_cudf
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
import socket

def load_data():
    # Placeholder for data loading logic
    return {"dummy": dask_cudf.DataFrame()}

def handle_client(client_socket, datasets):
    try:
        data = client_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip()
        if data:
            session_id, words_json = data.split(' ', 1)
            words = json.loads(words_json)
            combined_df = dask_cudf.DataFrame()
            total_ile = 0
            for word in words:
                if word in datasets:
                    combined_df = dask_cudf.concat([combined_df, datasets[word]])
                    total_ile += datasets[word]['ile'].unique().sum().compute()
            if not combined_df.empty:
                id_counts = combined_df['id'].value_counts().reset_index()
                id_counts.columns = ['id', 'count']
                combined_df = combined_df.merge(id_counts, on='id', how='left')
                combined_df['score'] = combined_df['score'] + (combined_df['count'] - 1) * 333
                grouped_df = combined_df.groupby('id').agg({'score': 'sum', 'domain_id': 'first'}).reset_index()
                top_results = grouped_df.nlargest(1000, 'score').compute().to_pandas().to_dict('records')
            else:
                top_results = []
            response = json.dumps({
                'session_id': session_id, 
                'data': top_results, 
                'response_time': time.time() - start_time,
                'ile': total_ile
            })
            client_socket.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.sendall(b"END\n")
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        client_socket.sendall(b"END\n")
    finally:
        client_socket.close()

def initialize_cluster():
    cluster = LocalCUDACluster(
        protocol='tcp',
        dashboard_address=':8787',
        CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1",
        rmm_pool_size="16GB"
    )
    client = Client(cluster)
    return client

def main():
    client = initialize_cluster()
    datasets = load_data()

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(("localhost", 9999))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    try:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while True:
                client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
                executor.submit(handle_client, client_socket, datasets)
    finally:
        server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Issues:
The workload is currently being handled by only one GPU.
I want to ensure that both GPUs are utilized effectively.
Questions:

How can I configure dask_cuda and my script to distribute the workload evenly across both GPUs?
Are there specific settings or configurations I might be missing?


my first comment is to put the main() module at the top since it is the entry point of the code.

Hi. Why are you sending datasets (empty?) through a socket? Dask cuda is correctly configured when you start the local cluster, but I'm not sure you are sending enough work to keep GPUs busy.
